# List of Lists in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, list, immutable.js

I want to have list of lists and push element to it, but I keep getting list with no elements and I can't think of the reason why.

I start with

```
List([ List([]), List([]) ]);
```

and I want to have

```
List([ List([2,4]), List([3,6]) ]);
```

The code I have is the following:

```
const { List } = require('immutable')

list = List([ List([]), List([]) ]);
list.get(0).push(2);
list.get(1).push(3);
list.get(0).push(4);
list.get(1).push(6);

console.log(list);
```

When I run it, it prints out:

```
List [ List [], List [] ]
```

There are no elements in the lists.

Comment: are you sure that the question is relative to javascript?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, immutable.js creates immutable arrays, which means the data cannot be changed... you are trying to push values onto an immutable array. Why are you doing this?

Comment: The OP is talking about Immutable's List collection and including it properly with `require`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Did you read the code? Pretty sure it's JS related

Comment: I believe OP is using `immutable.js` - https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: Side note - am I the only one who hates that this kind of stuff is creeping into JS?

Comment: @AndrewLi, no, I meant `List([ List([]), List([]) ])`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeah, that's valid JS with Immutable.js, and relates directly to JS

Comment: @mhodges It is amazing that this kind of stuff is getting into JS, if you know how and when to use it, like in Redux reducers for example :)

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo The problem is, many full stack developers are pushing hard for static typing, classes, and things of the nature of this question and wanting/expecting them to work just as they would in their respective strongly-typed server-side language. They do not know how the inner-workings of JavaScript work, how and why it is powerful, and how to leverage the language features that are not available in strongly typed languages. I'm looking at you, "let is the new var", "fat arrow is the new function", and "class is the new object" people!

Comment: @mhodges Totally agree with you on that. The fact that `class` is being pushed hard and taxonomy is getting into JS is concerning. TypeScript is also gaining a lot of ground which i don't think its a bad thing, but it concerns me to start seeing code written only in TypeScript because some people just cant live withouth "OOP" and taxonomy. But this is a community after all, and JS had these "for other languages" features since it came out, and its still an amazing language, let's hope for the best.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo That is what I meant by "people do not know the inner-workings of JavaScript". When people come up with libraries for things you can already do, many people in the community jump on it like it is some major breakthrough. It's been funny to watch, but as it creeps its way more and more into the language itself, it starts to concern me. This is a perfect example - what is wrong with `Object.freeze()` to make a plain js array immutable? Instead, it's using unfamiliar data types & api methods that have to be researched and are subject to change. What a future maintenance nightmare!

Comment: @mhodges Yes, I still think that's not the case with Immutable, as `Object.freeze()` wouldnt allow you to actually manipulate collections as good as Immutable does. Trust me, I use is extensively and it is awesome. I also tried to do the same stuff using vanilla JS and that really was a nightmare.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo Let's continue this in chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134629/room-for-mhodges-and-marco-scabbiolo

Answer (score 2):

Of course there will be no elements in the [List](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List).

When you do

```
list.get(0).push(2);
```

You are not mutating the element at the position `0` by pushing `2` into it as you're assuming, you're getting a new `List` that is the result of doing that operation, that's the point of Immutable, instead of mutating the original collection you get a fresh new one.

This is how you do what you're trying to do with Immutable:

```
const { List } = require('immutable')

list = List([ List([]), List([]) ]);
list = list.set(0, list.get(0).push(2));
list = list.set(1, list.get(1).push(3));
list = list.set(0, list.get(0).push(4));
list = list.set(1, list.get(1).push(6));

console.log(list);
```

> List [ List[2, 4], List[3, 6] ]

Comment: After all, it's named Immutable.js, so you'd expect your data structures to *be immutable* :) (PS: Good link to add: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List)

Comment: That makes totally sense. Thank you so much for your help!!